# Need to find if an option value has a substring, and if it does change the select to that value

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm making a select, out of a JSON, that appends every option. In the option value I pass the StateCode and Prefix of that state. Since the list is pretty big (<240 states), how to perform a check if the StateCode is inside the option value and automatically change to it.

```
var phonePrefixes = JSON.parse(country_phone_prefixes);
 var prefixSelect = $("select[id*='_prefix']");
        var currentCountry = $("body").attr("data-country");
        if (prefixSelect.length) {
            $.each(phonePrefixes, function(i,e){
                var $option = $('<option value="'+e.country_code+' '+e.phone_prefix+'">'+ e.name +' '+e.phone_prefix +'</option>');
                prefixSelect.append($option);
            });
            $(prefixSelect).val(currentCountry).change();
```

JSON :

```
[{
    "name": "Afghanistan",
    "phone_prefix": "+93",
    "country_code": "AF"
}, {
    "name": "Aland Islands",
    "phone_prefix": "+358",
    "country_code": "AX"
}, {
    "name": "Albania",
    "phone_prefix": "+355",
    "country_code": "AL"
}, {
    "name": "Algeria",
    "phone_prefix": "+213",
    "country_code": "DZ"
}, {
    "name": "American Samoa",
    "phone_prefix": "+1684",
    "country_code": "AS"
}, {
    "name": "Andorra",
    "phone_prefix": "+376",
    "country_code": "AD"
}]
```

Comment: Add a small part of `country_phone_prefixes` to the question